# In lldb, how do you print struct fields that are bitfields

Tags: c, lldb, bit-fields

I'm having trouble getting lldb to evaluate expression involving a bitfield

I have a struct that contains a bitfield

```
struct foobar {
    int a;
    unsigned short short_msb: 8;
    unsigned short short_lsb: 8;
}
struct foobar g_var = {10, 20, 30};
int main(void) { }
```

In LLDB 6.0, attempting to print the value of the bitfield fields results in an error.
I can evaluate the object g_var, but only all all at once, not the fields separately.

```sh
(lldb) po g_var
(struct foobar) $1 = {
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = 30
}
(lldb) po g_var.a
(int) $2 = 10
(lldb) po g_var.short_msb
error: suppose to interpret, but failed: Interpreter couldn't resolve a value during execution
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help debug code you won't show us?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: The question does not request debugging help.

Comment: Using Apple Clang 11.0.0 and LLDB 1100.0.30.11 on macOS 10.14.6, `po g_var.short_msb` produces “20”. What compiler are you using, with what command-line switches, what version of LLDB, and on what system?

Comment: lldb 6.0 is a couple of years old now.  If you can move up to a more recent version of lldb, you should give that a try.   We've fixed a lot of things in the meantime.

Comment: So I did some more testing. The original issue I had was with an ELF binary which which was produced by  gcc toolchain for powerpc. I ran a similar ELF output from x64 linux gcc and in that case LLDB was able to show the bitfield. Also, in both cases (gcc x86 and gcc powerpc) when I just output the variable itself without specifying a field in particular, it is able to show the correct values of all fields. I enabled more debugging and particular error is: 'Couldn't evaluate %bf.load = load i48, i48* %8, align 4'

Comment: if this still happens with lldb-9.0, please file a bug with http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Will do, I'll try that.

Comment: Just wanted to give an update. I didn't try lldb-9.0 yet, but I was able to work around the issue by using the Python API and was able to access the field values I needed programmatically.